# MFC - Catch Keyup Message Alt + Arrow

Tags: c++, mfc

How do you catch the keyup message after holding alt + arrow key down?

For example:  I am cycling through a list using the alt + left/right key and once the user stops and lets up on the alt key I want to catch that message so I can do some processing.  (Think like cycling through pages in Visual Studio with Ctrl + Tab, and once you highlight the tab you want it processes)

Current Code:

```
if ( pMsg->message == WM_SYSKEYUP )
{
  switch( pMsg->wParam )
  {
  case VK_LEFT:
  case VK_RIGHT:
      ProcessFunctionHere(pMsg->wParam);
      break;
  default:
    break;
  }

}
```

The problem with the above code is that it catches when the left/right arrow keys are let up not when the alt key is let up.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Shift+Alt+Ctrl are just the modifiers... When I press Alt+Tab I want to cyle through the Tasks and it shoudl stop when I press he Tab key... Why do you want it the other way round?

Comment: Because when the user is cycling through the list, there might be a pause in which task they want to select.  So I want it to process based off the ALT keyup. I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Then you have to trigger the VK_MENU key change by your own. But I am not sure what you want to do with thge repeated Tab Messages...

Comment: Turns out I was on the right path but I needed to catch the VK_MENU message on WM_KEYUP.

I'll come back with an answer later